# how to check for 10 digits

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a phone number field. To be a valid phone number there has to be only 10 digits. How can I look in my phone number field which numbers are not 10 digits and then delete them?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you dont have any '-' in the field,

```
mysql> DELETE FROM Table WHERE PHONE_NUM NOT RLIKE '[0-9]{10}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should validate it first before inserting the phone number into the database.

Although i believe that it is possible if you use

```
Delete from Table where (Select statement here);
```

But it's not going to reflect well in your overall program, in terms of performance and reusability